# Mountain Lion : Apt-get command not found

Tags: macos, kde-plasma, apt

I am trying to install KDE Desktop using command :  sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop. However, I keep getting error 'apt-get' Command not found. I tried installing flink and checked if it works. But I still get the same error. Can anyone help me with this please ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Check your PATH setting or provide the full path to apt-get.

Comment: Tried that. Doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're on a Mac. apt-get is a Debian command for Debians package manager.

If you want a Linux-like package manager on your Mac, you can try Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Try using brew install. This seems to work for me to replace apt-get.